# How can I animate multiple objects at once?

Tags: graphics, animation

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to do this project where I have to animate multiple circles.

I have 4 circles, each with `x = 1, 2, 3, 4` , respectively. Each `y` position is given by a function `F(x, n, t)`. I want to animate the circles with respect to `t`, manipulate `n` and have the four circles side-by-side.

I came up with this

```
Manipulate[
  Animate[
    Graphics[{Circle[{x, F[x, n, t]}, 0.2]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, 10}], 
  {n, 1, 4, 1}]
```

which works for a defined value of `x`.

Can anyone help me figure out how to animate for all values of x at the same time?

Comment: what's your F[x,n,t] !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define your F[x,n,t] also work in position x of F[x,n,t] if you want to place them side by side or above each other !???

Try this will help you

```
F[x_, n_, t_] := Sin[n*x*t];

Manipulate[Animate[Graphics[{
    {Red, Circle[{x + 2, F[x, n, t]}, 0.2]},
    {Blue, Circle[{x, F[x, n, t]}, 0.2]},
    {Black, Circle[{x + 1, F[x, n, t]}, 0.2]},
    {Green, Circle[{x - 1, F[x, n, t]}, 0.2]}
    }, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-2, 2}}],
  {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}], {n, 1, 4, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The function was defined, I just didn't feel like writing it here. That did do it. Is there any way to make it more compact? Maybe with a cycle for the values of x or something?